# Error message icon shown with PLAIN_MESSAGE parameter on a JOptionPane object

Tags: java, swing, icons, joptionpane

I create a dialog using JOptionPane manually using the codes below

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(feedbackPanel, JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
pane.setOptions(options);
pane.setInitialValue(options[0]);
pane.setIcon(null);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Your feedback");
dialog.setLocation(contentPane.getLocation());
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Note that I pass in JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE when creating the JOptionPane object, however, the dialog still displays a ERROR_MESSAGE icon along with everything else. I would like to get rid of the icon (i.e having no icon at all). Does anyone know where the problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your JOptionPane constructor parameters switched around:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(feedbackPanel, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
```

It's `JOptionPane(message, messageType, optionType)`

EDITED:

Also:  optionType should be one of `{DEFAULT_OPTION, YES_NO_OPTION, YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, OK_CANCEL_OPTION}`

`YES_OPTION` is used for the return values.

Comment: Oops... That explains! Thanks!